# nodejs > Express > SQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

I am trying to INSERT INTO my SQL Server DB Table using nodejs (Express).

Everything I have tried will not work.

In my app.js I have the below which executes correctly and connects, however where i am struggling is, how do i get data inserted in to my DB table.

**app.js**

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
var async = require('async');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var sql = require('mssql');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var homepage = require('./routes/homepage');
var app = express();

////// DB CONF //////
var config = {
  userName: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxxxx',
  server: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
  options: {
      database: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
}
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected');
  }
});
```

Comment: For the sake of sanity, format your code :/

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: What you get in the console while running?

Comment: @Obsolete01, your code is incomplete, you have to show us what you are trying to insert !! please edit your question and add what you have tried

Comment: when it runs it says "connected" so i know the above is working. What I am asking is for help on how to insert data in to my table. For example ... my DB server is called apples .. I have a table called orange. I want to insert data in to my table. In that table I have 3 x columns .. The data I want to inset is "monday" "tuesday" "wednesday".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already included mysql library. now you have to create mysql connection. Like:

```
const writeDB = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '********',
    database: 'dbName'
});
```

after creating connection run query like:

```
        let squerySet = "INSERT INTO weekDays (`id`, `date`, `day`) values ('1','2018-03-03', 'Monday');"
        writeDB.query(squerySet,(err, result) => {
            if(err){
                return reject(err)
            }
            else {
                resolve("carrierbillreceipt Table COPY DONE .....")
            }
        })
```

Because `writeDB.query` will return a promise then you have to handle this by creating this in promise. Like:

```
 const insertDays = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let squerySet = "INSERT INTO weekDays (`id`, `date`, `day`) values ('1','2018-03-03', 'Monday');"
        writeDB.query(squerySet,(err, result) => {
            if(err){
                return reject(err)
            }
            else {
                resolve("insertDays Insert DONE .....")
            }
        })
    })
}
```

you can also insert an JSON object. Like:

```
let data = { "id": '1', "date":'2018-03-03', "day": 'Monday'}
writeDB.query(`INSERT INTO weekDays SET ?;`,[data],(err, result) => {
   if(err){
       return reject(err)
   }
   else {
       resolve("insertDays Insert DONE .....")
   }
})
```